# Connecting an outdoor light

Tags: electrical, outdoor, connectors

I need to connect a flood light to the exterior of my house. Previously, an on-wall lamp was installed, and this is how the exterior wall looks like after I uninstalled it. There are 3 sets of wires, though I'm going to use only one set.

[image: wall]

This is the flood light I need to connect. Note that I can not replace its cable as the body is IP65 sealed and can not be dismantled.

[image: light]

What would be a correct and aesthetic way to install the flood light?

Comment: Where on this planet are you?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: Israel

Comment: Also, is it possible to install a box recessed into the existing wall?

Comment: Probably not. It is right on top of the balcony door, and most likely there is a concrete beam over there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing there was an old light exactly there?  And that light happened to have an integral junction box which housed the wiring splices?

You'll need to install an appropriate outdoor junction box for your country's wiring methods.  Then mount the light either independently, or I have been known to mount it on the junction box lid.  Then create a proper entry for that cord into the junction box, and splice it therein.

Comment: Thank you, that's the obvious solution. However, I'm afraid that a junction box would be really ugly.

Comment: @LiorKogan that's... why I bolt the light to the junction box cover.  If a junction box is not acceptable, then, you have painted yourself into a corner. Most jurisdictions will not let you splice outside a junction box - least of all outdoors!  ....The only alternative then is to get behind that wall, suck all the wiring back through the hole including the light cord, and make the splice there.  Inside a junction box.

Comment: @LiorKogan - You have purchased a floodlight with a yoke mounting, If you do not want to install a box. Your only other option would be to take the fixture back and exchange it for a standard wall pack that mounts flush to the wall and is connected through the back.

Answer (score 0):

This is something I thought about. I'm not sure if it is a good idea, and would love to hear some opinions.

1. Wrap all wall wires together with shrink tubing
2. Pass the wall wires into a flexible conduit
3. Use a second shrink tubing to join the wrapped wall wires and the end of the conduit
4. Terminate/connect the light cable to the wall wires inside the conduit using twist-on wire connectors (the conduit should be wide enough)
5. use a third shrink tubing on the other side of the conduit and over the light cable

Both conduit and shrink tubing would be white of course, and I believe it may look quite nice.

Comment: NEC 334.40 (B) States you can splice wire without boxes in exposed cable wiring for repair wiring in existing buildings. But the material must be approved for such use (UL Listed) and application. Also note the word exposed, meaning you must be able to maintain the splice. Now if you are asking any electrician if he would accept what you have proposed, I don't think anyone would, including myself. You're better off installing a surface or recessed box and doing it correctly and safely.